# getJSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

I am new to html and javascript.As far as i know the following code should give an alert when i press "Get JSON Data" button.But the page is not giving me any response.Any help is greatly appreciated.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:5000/2", function(result){
                    if (result.length == 0){
                        alert("nothing") ;
                    }
                    if (result.length){
                        alert("success") ;
                    }    
                    // $("div").append(myObject);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button>Get JSON data</button>
    <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what does your developer console log says?

Comment: what is the result in new page when you write http://127.0.0.1/2 address bar? If you have an installed IIS in your local, you must publish a default site. Your tried address want to reach your local IIS default web page with default variable to value of 2.

Comment: @Nomesh DeSilva I have no idea what this is but it's giving me this error "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:5000/2. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the JSON call with

```
$.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:5000/2", function(result){
        if (result.length == 0){
            alert("nothing") ;
        }
        if (result.length){
            alert("success") ;
        }    
        // $("div").append(myObject);
    }).fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
       var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
       console.log( "Request Failed: " + err )
    });
```

That way you can see what goes wrong. The javascript looks OK, I suspect it's a server issue.

You could also try getting back JSON from some random source, like http://1882.no/API/business/get/results.php?q=skole&page=0

Comment: Yes,It must be the error with server.But with the server you gave it's working.But what i don't understand is i am getting the desired result when i run "curl -i http://localhost:5000/2" which is 
{
  "data": [
    "{\"lat\": 28.4594965, \"lng\": 77.0266383, \"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"55656cdfcb682e138eadf64e\"}, \"num\": 3, \"title\": \"#OnePlustwo launching on June 01 ??? i just heard .. is it ?? really ???\"}"
  ]
}

Comment: OK, so it's a CORS issue then. You have to enable CORS on your server, but beware that this opens the server to anyone if you are open to the internet.

What server software are you using?

This website should be able to help: http://enable-cors.org/

Comment: I have no personal experience with flask, but this blogpost seems to be of help: http://www.davidadamojr.com/handling-cors-requests-in-flask-restful-apis/

Please post your own answer if that is the solution, including code, in case the website goes down and someone finds this question later :)

Answer (score 1):

I suspected that should be the Cross-domain issue. That is why I asked for the console log. you have couple of choices:

- config the cross-domain headers from your servlet/backend response.
  (ex: if you're using a Servlet:)

  `response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');`
- use **jsonp** call back

  `$.getJSON("http://example.com/something.json?callback=?", function(result){
     //response data are now in the result variable
     alert(result);
  });`

> The **"?"** on the end of the URL tells jQuery that it is a JSONP
>   request instead of JSON. jQuery registers and calls the callback
>   function automatically.

- use **$.ajax** with **CORS** enabled or with **jsonp**

```js
 ex:
   $.ajax({
     url: surl,
     data: { 
       id: id  // data to be sent to server
     },
     dataType: "jsonp",
     jsonp: "callback",
     jsonpCallback: "jsonpcallback"
   });

 // Named callback function from the ajax call when event fired.
 function jsonpcallback(rtndata) {
   // Get the id from the returned JSON string and use it to reference the target jQuery object.
   var myid = "#" + rtndata.id;
   $(myid).feedback(rtndata.message, {
     duration: 4000,
     above: true
   });
 }
```

- or else, download and configure **"CORS.jar"** in your server side which will allow the cross-domain requests.
  **[HOW ?](http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter-installation.html)**

Hope you can get some idea. follow which suits for you ..